# How to read from text file

Tags: vb.net, readfile

How do you read the username and passwords so that they can be entered into a login? I have the usernames and passwords in the external files, but when I run the program and type in a correct it just comes up with the "sorry, username or password is invalid, please try again" error message I made comes up.

```
Public Class Form3
Dim filereader1 As System.IO.StreamReader
Dim filereader2 As System.IO.StreamReader
Dim username2, password1 As String
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If TextBox1.Text = Nothing Then
        MsgBox("You need to enter your username and password in the textboxes", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Error")
    ElseIf TextBox2.Text = Nothing Then
        MsgBox("You need to enter your username and password in the textboxes", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Error")
        Me.Show()
        filereader1 = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader("C:\Users\ryanm_000\Documents\username.txt")
        filereader2 = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader("C:\Users\ryanm_000\Documents\password.txt")
        username2 = filereader1.ReadLine
        password1 = filereader2.ReadLine
    ElseIf TextBox1.Text = username2 And TextBox2.Text = password1 Then
        Me.Hide()
        My.Forms.Form5.Text = Now.ToString
        My.Forms.Form5.Show()
    Else
        MsgBox("Sorry, username or password is invalid, please try again", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Error")

    End If


End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint and watch your code execute. The problem will become clear.  Then read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: well, it seems that your last `ElseIf` is about 4 lines to low, other option you leave textbox2.text empty (though I am not sure if Nothing will hit for a textbox, maybe `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox2.Text)` would be better), and the second time you give it in correctly

Comment: @Icepickle i did your code but it made no difference in that it still doesn't read from the text file properly

Comment: Update the question, but you should really debug as @Plutonix suggested

Comment: Getting to the root of the issue may not be as apparent to someone who is new to .Net as it is to those of us that are familiar with its idiosyncrasies...  Such as using String.Equals() to compare strings instead of using the = sign

Answer (score 1):

Your conditions are in an incorrect style. you must do with this style. Also, you can use some better ways to create a login page, like use database or an XML file.

```
If TextBox1.Text = Nothing Or TextBox2.Text = Nothing Then
                MsgBox("You need to enter your username and password in the textboxes", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Error")
            Else
                filereader1 = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader("C:\Users\ryanm_000\Documents\username.txt")
            filereader2 = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader("C:\Users\ryanm_000\Documents\password.txt")
            username2 = filereader1.ReadLine
            password1 = filereader2.ReadLine

            If TextBox1.Text = username2 And TextBox2.Text = password1 Then
                Me.Hide()
                My.Forms.Form5.Text = Now.ToString
                My.Forms.Form5.Show()
            Else
                MsgBox("Sorry, username or password is invalid, please try again", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Error")

            End If
        End If
```